# Redirect to page with basic auth

Tags: http, session, redirect, payment-gateway, basic-authentication

I'm testing a payment solution where a user is redirected to some offsite payment gateway to enter in their payment credentials. Once payment is successful the user is then redirected back to my site.

My site is still in development so it's protected by some basic auth.

The browser has the authentication details saved so the post back seems to work but some session variables I had set now seem to be missing.

Could this be caused by the basic auth settings?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be possible to bypass the BasicAuth protection if you allow the IP from the payment provider/gateway in your virtual host or .htaccess file with an `Allow from IP`, for example for an Apache virtual host by

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ..
  AuthType basic
  AuthName "My cool test server"
  Require valid-user
  AuthUserFile /home/myuser/etc/htpasswd
  Allow from x.y.z.z
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: That request comes from Customer browser not payment gateway.

Comment: If the user is redirected back from the payment gateway the gateway makes the redirect, right? If we know the IP addresses from the gateway, then we can enter them as exceptions in the VHost config file.

Comment: No, Customer clicks Pay button, request go to payment gateway, payment gateway usually sends HTTP 302 response, Customer browser gets the URL from  response and does a request (to our server)